# How override java class by order of loading?

Tags: java, class, jar

It is possible to have 2 jars with the same name of class. Does it possible control which class will be loaded(used) by JVM ?
Thanks.

Comment: I've never tried this, but I believe that the first jar in the classpath that contains the class will be the one used, i.e., you can control which class will be loaded by putting the jars on your classpath in that order. That being said, this probably isn't a good idea...

Comment: No good can come of this. Turn back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two jar with the same class, which one will be loaded depends on the order of the jars.  You can also create your own class loader, and chain it to the parent class loader.  Therefore your class loader will try to load the class, and if it fails, it will fall back to parent.  Take a look at this one for example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html

Comment: From what depends order of jars?

Comment: Actually this is not correct. If you use a URLClassLoader, first the parent classloader is used to look for a class. If it cannot find the specified class, only then the child will be used.

Comment: Normally the order of the jars depends on how they are defined in the class path if declared explicitly.  If using a directory scanning classloader, for example when running inside Apache Tomcat, the file ordering is up to Operating System.  It's normally alphabetically, but you have no control over it.

Comment: Yep Bruno is correct. It's rather important to FIRST let the parent classloader try to load the class before trying yourself. Otherwise you may get extremely strange results when other classes try to access the class. I assume you could violate this if you really knew what you were doing and had complete control over the whole application that uses the concerned classes, but it seems not the best idea.

Comment: Voo, yes, you can violate this by implementing a custom class loader and overriding some methods (findClass? don't remember exactly). I've done it once when playing with some kind of dynamic plugins system (in order to isolate different plugins into different class loaders and be able to unload all their classes from memory and free  PermGen once the plugin is deactivated -- and avoid OOM; something like what Tomcat does when redeploying an application). It is a very specific need, and one must understand really well how class loading works in Java to do it properly.

Comment: What I really can't understand is how a downvoted, wrong answer can be marked as accepted. It is useless to flag this, moderators usually reply that flags should not be used to report such problems.

Comment: @BrunoReis Yes you can do it, you just have to guarantee that classes loaded from different classloaders only interoperate in such a way that they only need classes that were loaded by a common classloader of their hierarchy. I assume it's doable, but I don't really see the advantage for the headaches - just simpler to follow the convention.

Comment: Voo, the advantage, as I said, is that you are able to unload classes and free memory. This is a very specific need though.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and it will simply load the one that appears first on the classpath.

Comment: Which jars appears first? Alphabetical?

Comment: The one which is the first is the first one in the -cp option : java -cp firstJar.jar;secondJar.jar ... If the jars are dynamically loaded by a web container from WEB-INF/lib, for example, then I don't think it's specified. You have to check with the container. But I wouldn't count on this.